# Изменение стиля одного div-блока при наведении мыши на другой div-блок

Tags: html, hover, css, классы

Имеем главный div-блок с "background: #fff" (div1).
Внутри этого блока находятся два других div-блока: 
div11 - картинка с фильтром "grayscale: 100%" (черно-белая) и
div12 - текст со стилем "display:none" (текст скрыт).

Итого, имеем такую структуру:

```
<div class="div1"> блок со стилем background:#FFF
        <div class="div11"> картинка с фильтром grayscale 100% </div>
        <div class="div12"> текст со стилем display:none </div>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при наведении мыши на главный div1-блок происходило сразу 3 процесса:

1. Менялся цвет фона в блоке div1.
2. В блоке div11 фильтр grayscale был равен 0%.
3. В блоке div12 стиль стал display:block.

Т.е. должно получиться так:

```
<div class="div1"> background:#F00
            <div class="div11"> картинка с фильтром grayscale 0% </div>
            <div class="div12"> текст со стилем display:block </div>
    </div>
```

Как это сделать?
Как заставить hover одного блока указывать стиль для других блоков?

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внезапно меня осенило:

```
div1:hover {
background: #f00;
}

div1:hover div11{
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
-o-filter: grayscale(0%);
filter: none;
}

div1:hover div12{
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/j7z1s31g/

HTML

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div11"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kfMqJ_gNFqI/TxhBpIguhNI/AAAAAAAAABU/lFKF147J_Pc/s150-c/photo.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="div12">текст со стилем display:none</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{}
.div1{
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;    
}
.div11 img{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.div12{
    display: none;    
}

.div1:hover{
    background: #ccc;    
}
.div1:hover img{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
.div1:hover .div12{
    display: block;
    /*color: #fff;*/
    font-size: 16px;
}
```