# При наведении на один тег скрывать другой?

Tags: css

Нужно при наведении мышкой, например, на header, скрывать footer, как это сделать посредством css?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Изменение стиля одного div-блока при наведении мыши на другой div-блок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/395947/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-div-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-div-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо, чтобы элементы в HTML располагались на одном уровне вложенности:

```
<header class="header">Шапка</header>
<main class="main">Контент</main>
<footer class="footer">Подвал</footer>
```

Для управления стилем родственных элементов используется символ тильды (~):

```
.header:hover ~ .footer {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Разве это так важно чтобы на одном уровне? А если скрываемый элемент вложен в какой то тег на том же уровне ? Можно просто указать путь до него, нет?

Comment: Я дал максимально точный ответ на поставленный автором вопрос. Отвечая на Ваш вопрос безусловно, указав путь мы можем повлиять на вложенные элементы.

Answer (score 0):

Если `footer` находиться внутри `header`'a то:

```
header:hover footer{стили}
```

Сразу после `header`'а то:

```
header:hover + footer{стили}
```

На одном уровне с `header`'ом то:

```
header:hover ~ footer{стили}
```

Является первым дочерним `header`'а то:

```
header:hover > footer{стили}
```

Answer (score 0):

3 способа, через *~* или *+* или вложенный селектор

При *+* элементы должны быть рядом и на одном уровне
При *~* элементы должны быть только на одном уровне

```
header:hover ~ footer {
  display: none
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/GTech1256/pen/mdbYdvd